# Use VM to test Gaming Software?

Tags: virtual-machine, fullscreen, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to test a Video Game (Sims2) in VMware Workstation 12. The VM runs on Windows 10. Installing the game was no problem, but when I start the game, it goes automatically into **fullscreen Mode and the Display of my VM gets black**. I can hear the sound of the game and I see the coursour, but Icant do anything.

The system Requirements are:

> CPU Speed: 800 MHz with a T&L capable Video Card (2.0 GHz without
>   Hardware T&L Video Card)
>
> RAM: 256 MB
>
> Video Card: 32 MB 3D accelerated video card (NVIDIA GeForce2/ATI
>   Radeon VE/Intel Extreme Graphics or better)
>
> DirectX version: 8.1
>
> Sound Card: Yes
>
> Free Disk Space: 3.5 GB

**How can I fix this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DirectX version: 8.1 (included) 
Are you sure the game isn't dx9+?

Drivers might be the problem.

Comment: Possible that it could be dx9, but this isn't an answer. you seem to be new on this side, so I'll explain it to you. You only answer if you have the answer to the question. If you have a question or want to say something about the Question, say it in a comment please. You can add a comment by clicking "add a comment" underneath the question. :D

Comment: Can't add comments yet, it's quite annoying :/

Comment: Ouu, well then, do you have a solution to my problem?

Comment: Can you up the graphics card to a dx9 compatible one? Is there no driver update available?

Comment: I'll try it, but i'm not sure if you're able to update drivers in a virtual machine.